# CoffeeLint: Disable Warning message: Line exceeds maximum allowed length

Tags: visual-studio-code, coffeescript, coffeelint

I'm trying to disable the warning message from CoffeLint in visual studio code.
I've changed the coffeelint.json  in my user folder to have the following:

```
    "max_line_length": {
    "name": "max_line_length",
    "level": "ignore"
},
```

But this has had no effect, the error message is still shown. Anyone can suggest whats wrong?

Comment: what do you mean in your "user folder"? I believe the vs code coffeelint extension reads coffeelint.json from the root of the workspace that you have opened. Is that the file that you have added those lines to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

To configure coffeescript once installed there will be a default coffeelint.json in the C:\Users\ [username] \.vscode\extensions folder. This was entirly useless and changing configuration here has no effect (atleast in my case).

To solve this problem create a new coffeelint.json in the root of your project or add a coffeelintConfig section to your package.json. Either way, the configuration is exactly the same. If CoffeeLint doesn't find any configuration for the current project, it will check for a $HOME/coffeelint.json to use.

Following this an example configuration is below:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "coffeelintConfig": {
    "indentation" : {
        "level" : "error",
        "value" : 4
    },
    "line_endings" : {
        "value" : "unix",
        "level" : "error"
    }
  }
}
```

coffeelint.json

```
{
  "indentation" : {
    "level" : "error",
    "value" : 4
  },
  "line_endings" : {
    "value" : "unix",
    "level" : "error"
  }
}
```

Now you can just edit this config to Lint your CoffeeScript :)

Comment: As of today, this doesn't work. There isn't a coffeelint.json file in either my ~/ dir, or within my workspace in the VScode editor. There is no section in my .code-workspace file either. And when I edit the package.json for my project to add line_endings, level: ignore, that has zero effect.