# How to disable "Class name should be UpperCamelCased" warning in coffeelint?

Tags: coffeescript, linter

I am using `coffeelint` I have a huge project that I want to increase quality and find potential bugs in the code. I started using `coffeelint` tool for `CoffeeScript` part of the project.

I encountered with `warning` that is not possible to address into the current code base.

I want to disable the following warning:

> Class name should be UpperCamelCased

I found similar [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982820/coffeelint-disable-warning-message-line-exceeds-maximum-allowed-length). The problem is where I can find documentation to tune parameters for my `coffelint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, its official site is being down at this moment.
You can create config file via

```
coffeelint --makeconfig > coffeelint.json
```

Place it somewhere under your project root directory.
And open the file to change `camel_case_classes`'s level into `ignore`

```
"camel_case_classes" : {
    "level" : "ignore"
  }
```